# Applying direction into current transform position

Tags: c#, transform, unity-game-engine

I'm not quite sure whether I pick correct title for the question, feel free to edit it If you find it misleading.

I'm developing an action game which involving music as the core of its gameplay.
It contains a set of entities (game objects) that move into several directions; top, right, left, bottom and diagonal moves (e.g: top-left, top-right, bottom-left, etc etc).

To determine the position of these entities, there is a value which need to be calculated that involving the music tempo and several properties of the entities itself, which I able produce it in Unity.

I use following function to determine the position of transform of the entities:

```
    private Vector3 _position;

    private void DeterminePosition(float offset)
    {
        // In actual code, the _position is initialized under Start() method
        // But for this simplification sake, I'll just put it here
        _position = _position == null ? new Vector3(0, 0, 1f) : _position;

        if (Direction == Direction.Up || Direction == Direction.RightUp || Direction == Direction.LeftUp)
        {
            _position.y = offset;
        }
        if (Direction == Direction.Down || Direction == Direction.RightDown || Direction == Direction.LeftDown)
        {
            _position.y = -offset;
        }
        if (Direction == Direction.Left || Direction == Direction.LeftDown || Direction == Direction.LeftUp)
        {
            _position.x = -offset;
        }
        if (Direction == Direction.Right || Direction == Direction.RightDown || Direction == Direction.RightUp)
        {
            _position.x = offset;
        }

        transform.position = _position;
    }
```

Where the `offset` is the value that I was talking about before.

The code works perfectly as intended, however the game need to be change.
Instead of fixed direction (e.g: Up, Right, Left, Bottom, RightUp, DownLeft etc etc) we decide to use value of degree for the direction (0 to 360 degree).

And now I've no idea how to impement this. I've tried to use following codes, but it doesn't work:

```
    _position = new Vector3(offset, offset, transform.position.z);

    // Where the direction is between 0 .. 360
    transform.position = Quaternion.Euler(0, direction, 0) * _position;
```

Can anybody else come up with solution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `offset` represents the distance from the new position to `(0, 0, transform.position.z)` (calling that the origin since only `x` and `y` positions seem to change), and `direction` is the angle measured counterclockwise in degrees between the positive x-axis and the vector from the origin to the the new position, you can get the new `x` and `y` positions using `offset` and *sin* and *cos* of the `direction`:

```
_position.x = offset * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * direction);
_position.y = offset * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * direction);
_position.z = transform.position.z; //assuming the z position stays the same
transform.position = _position;
```

**Edit**

To account for scaling, I think you will need to replace `offset` depending on the `direction`.

```
float multiplier = 0f;
if(0 <= direction && direction <= 45)
{
    multiplier = Mathf.Abs(offset / Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * direction));
}
else if(45 < direction && direction <= direction <= 135)
{
    multiplier = Mathf.Abs(offset / Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * direction));
}
else if(135 < direction && direction <=225)
{
    multiplier = Mathf.Abs(offset / Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * direction));
}
else if(225 < direction && direction <= 315)
{
    multiplier = Mathf.Abs(offset / Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * direction));
}
else if(315 < direction && direction <= 360)
{
    multiplier = Mathf.Abs(offset / Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * direction));
}

_position.x = multiplier * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * direction);
_position.y = multiplier * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * direction);
_position.z = transform.position.z;
transform.position = _position;
```

This will break the coordinate plane into 4 90-degree sections (if you combine `315 < direction <= 360` and `0 <= direction < 45`) where you are using *sin* or *cos* of `direction` to create a multiplier that should account for the regions where `offset` needs to be scaled depending on `x` and `y` components of the displacement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is ALMOST correct (it indeed works, but..) I forgot to mention that the game arena shape is square rather than circle. In my previous implementation before using degree, when the entity goes into corner (topleft, topright, etc) the transform position match with the tempo (when music offset reach into 0, the entity hit the border of the arena). However when I update with ur implementation, the entity seems a bit slower, the music offset reach 0 but the entity is not even hit the border of the arena. It somewhat transform the arena into circle rather than square.

Comment: However, if the entity move straight forward, the transform position and the music offset seems to be matching (e.g the direction is 180 degree)

Comment: Following picture describe what happening: http://imgur.com/e780D88 or this: http://imgur.com/tmLY4Pt

Comment: Hi @SirusDoma. What are the boundaries of the arena? I think `offset` needs to be scaled. If the entity has a `direction` that divides 90 (moving only in a direction parallel to X or Y axis), the magnitude of `transform.position` will be `offset`. Previously, if the entity was moving diagonally, the magnitude of `transform.position` would be `sqrt(2) * offset`, but now, the magnitude will always be `offset`, regardless of direction, so the distance will be shorter now.

Comment: boundaries of the arena is just visual representation, the distance between center of the arena (where the entity is spawned) to the border is 5f (I don't really know what measurement type in unity). Then how to adjust (or scale) it? also it seems the sin and cos are in wrong order, seems it suppose to be sin for x and cos for y

Comment: I will look into this some more; what you describe sounds like a result of the maximum distance now being `offset`. One thing that might be worth a quick try is replace `offset` in the equations with `Mathf.Abs(offset / Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * direction))`. When `direction == 45`, the result will be `sqrt(2) * offset`, and when `direction == 0`, the result will be `offset`. (I am not sure about the values between; still need to investigate. Also, watch out for dividing by 0).

Comment: I tried your formula, well indeed it return what you expect, when the `direction` is 45, the offset equal with `sqrt(2) * offset` and when the `direction` is 0, the result equal to `offset`. However the entity seems moving too fast, especially when moving into certain direction...